# why cannot show the dynamic text?

Tags: flash

I had create a dynamic text with initial text "0".

When run this code, the text will change

```
if (hammer_mc.hammerCollision_mc.hitTestObject(this[names].moleCollision_mc)) {
        score++;
        upCount--;
        scoretext.text = int(score).toString();         
    }
```

scoretext.text is the dynamic text variable.

I checked and confirm that the variable got increase but cannot display it out.

Comment: try this `scoretext.embedFonts = false;` after upCount--;

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that should work.  Here are some things to check:

- the font is embedded (necessary for non-system fonts in dynamic text fields)
- the text field is large enough
- the font size is appropriate
- the font color is not the same as the background color